# set y axis values as zero for nonexisting x axis values in jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I am using jqplot to create a graphic.
I have an issue about the nonexisting values.
I create a graphic with 5 lines as shown http://www.popularjava.net/wp-content/uploads/statisticGraphic.png 
As you see from the picture, there is only one value for some lines such as orange line.
However, I would like to show such nonexisting values with y=0.
I mean, I want to put y=0 for all dates if there is no point for any date.

Here is my code.

```
var minGraphicXValue = response.minGraphicXValue;
var maxGraphicXValue = response.maxGraphicXValue;
var dataSeriesList = response.dataSeriesList;

 var plot1 = $.jqplot('countGraphicGrid', response.countArray, {
                title: 'Count/Time Graphic - ' + selectedItemType + ":" + itemValue + " - " + StatisticGraphic.selectedGraphicPeriod,
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        label: "Time",
                        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                        labelOptions: {
                            fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                            fontSize: '14pt'
                        },
                        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: StatisticGraphic.tickFormatPattern,
                            angle: -30
                        },
                        tickInterval: StatisticGraphic.tickIntervalTime,
                        min: minGraphicXValue,
                        max: maxGraphicXValue,
                        drawMajorGridlines: false
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        label: "Count",
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString: '%d'
                        },
                        min: 0,
                        max: 100,
                        autoscale: true
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    placement: 'outside'
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    rendererOptions: {
                        smooth: true,
                        animation: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    },
                    showMarker: true
                },
                series: dataSeriesList,
                highlighter: {
                    show: true,
                    sizeAdjust: 7.5,
                    tooltipOffset: 9
                },
                grid: {
                    background: 'rgba(57,57,57,0.0)',
                    drawBorder: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    gridLineColor: '#666666',
                    gridLineWidth: 1
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to format your data before your render them on your plot.

I mean add values for your nonexisting ones. You can use your (min|max)GraphicXValue and set them to 0 if non existing.

Comment: I cant format my data before I render them as I dont know the x axis values in advance. They are dynamic values and represent any time or date. I cannot know how many points there will be in x axis and what their values are.